# JavaScript Select within a Select

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a drop down menu, with two options:

```
<select name="chs" value="" id = ""/>
                <option value="">ICE Cream</option>
                <option value="">Juice</option>
</select>
```

This is what I want to have: in the first page you see a select, with two option, if you choose ICE cream another select will appear with different flavors (chocolate, vanilla, etc), and the same for juice.

This is what I already have:

html:

```
<label>Choose Skin</label><br /><select name="na" value="" id = ""/>
            <option value="">ICE Cream</option>
            <option value="">Juice</option>
        </select>
        <select name="icecreamfla" value="" onchange="showSelect()" id = "framework"/>
            <option id="jm">vanilla</option>
            <option id = "wp">chocholate</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name = "redirect" value="go" />
```

The JavaScript:

```
function showSelect()
    {
        var select = document.getElementById('skin');
         if(select.value == "juice"){
            alert('saeed khare!');
         }
         else{
            var option = document.getElementById('icecreamfla');
            option.style.display = 'inline';
         }
    }
```

`option.style.display` used to be 'none', then I changed it to inline.
if any one can help please do it.

Comment: the basic idea is that you a select and if you choose anything on that select, depending on what you choose another select will appear with different options. so if you choose for ice cream in the first select, a second select will appear automatically in this case you can choose for different flavor. THANKS FOR THE HEADS UP, I WILL WORK ON THAT.

Comment: @Saeed there are problems with your HTML. You are _closing_ the `<select>` elements on the opening tag. `<select><option></option></select>` is the correct markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want to do it .

```
       <script language='javascript'>

            function showSelect()
            {
               var select = document.getElementById('skin').value;
               if(select == "ICE Cream"){
             var str="<select name='icecreamfla' value=''  id = 'icecreamfla'/>"
                   +"<option id='jm'>vanilla</option>"+
                    "<option id ='wp'>chocholate</option> </select>";
                     document.getElementById("flavour").innerHTML=str;   

                                      }
            }
```

```
   <label>Choose Skin</label><br /><select name="na" value="" id = "skin" onchange="showSelect()">
        <option value="ICE Cream">ICE Cream</option>
        <option value="Juice">Juice</option>
    </select>
    <div id="flavour"></div>

    <input type="submit" name = "redirect" value="go" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [**small demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fY7pg/) with the flavours `<select>` only appearing when *Ice Cream* is selected.

It should be easy to follow to implement this to display a different `<select>` if the user chooses *Juice*.

**Edit:** If you want the selected *value* you can use `types.options[types.selectedIndex].text` to get it using the variables in my demo.